# Computations involving the real projective plane

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $H$ be the complement of two open disks in the projective plane $\mathbb{R}P^2$. Determine all connected surfaces that arise as $3-$fold covers of $H$.

I think two such 3-fold covers are $\mathbb{R}P^2$ itself and  $S^2$. But how do I find the rest? Is there any general method that I can apply>

Comment: Your proposed answer is incorrect. $H$ is a surface-with-boundary, and it's boundary $\partial H$ is not empty. It follows every cover of $H$ is also a surface-with-boundary whose boundary is not empty. That completely rules out $\mathbb RP^2$ and $S^2$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for the comment. Can you give me a hint as to how I can find the correct 3-fold covers?

Comment: Hint: $3$-fold covers correspond $1$-$1$ with index $3$ subgroups of the fundamental group. So your first task is to determine the fundamental group of your space.